# Image not fitting

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to load an image as a background in pygame.  I have done this before, and followed the same process, but with my latest game it is showing up wonky and I'm not sure why...
My original image (below) is 1280x645 and I use this code to load/display it:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,645))    
bg = pygame.image.load('CheeseFarm_Background.png')

win.blit(bg, (0,0))
```

[image: Original image]

But, when I run it, it looks like this:

[image: What I see]

Ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough code to say what could be the problem.  The image in the post works fine for me.  Obviously your code has no event loop, so probably the window closes immediately.  I expect the code was omitted to make the question smaller.

The code below opens a window and displays the bitmap from the question correctly.

```
import pygame

### initialisation
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,645))    
bg = pygame.image.load('dairy_farm.png')


### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
            # On mouse-click
            mouse = event.pos
            print( "Click at " + str( mouse ) )

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Yea, I left out the rest to shorted the post.  But, I ran your code in a separate main and got the same result as before.
I am using repl.it to run pygame...perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: @LeeJones - possibly, I've never used repl.it

Comment: @LeeJones Try to make a [mcve]. Too much code is often too verbose, but leaving out too much can get rid of valuable information. Try to remove things from your code that aren't necessary to reproduce the problem until you create an example that's small enough to post and still contains the issue. Otherwise, it's going to be hard to figure out what the problem might be.